# Formulario html

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Me pueden orientar como puede crear un formulario como se muestra en esta imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Lo quieres con Bootstrap? Quieres alguna restricción en los caracteres o tamaño? Intenta extender un poco tu pregunta y mostrar que es lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías consultar la documentación oficial de Bootstrap:

[Sección de columns y rows](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

Tu formulario podría quedar algo asi...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <strong>Responsable</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <strong>Fecha</strong>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <strong>Nombre:</strong> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <strong>Apellido:</strong> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <strong>Dirección:</strong> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                text
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                text
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```